# ReportLab ListFlowable use custom bullet

Tags: python, reportlab

I'm using Python 2.7 with reportlab to generate my PDF file. I want to change the bullet style, e.g I want to use dash `-` or check `✓` or cross `x` instead in the default numbering (1 2 3 4 5 ...)

Here is my code :

```
styles = getSampleStyleSheet()
style = styles["Normal"]

t = ListFlowable(
[
Paragraph("Item no.1", style),
ListItem(Paragraph("Item no. 2", style),bulletColor="green",value=7),
Paragraph("Item no.4", style),
],
bulletType='1'
)

data = [[t, t, t, t]]

table = Table(data, colWidths=(4.83*cm))

table.setStyle(TableStyle([
                       ('BOX', (0,0), (-1,-1), 0.7, colors.black)
                       ]))

table.wrapOn(pdf, width, height)
table.drawOn(pdf, *coord(1.1, 21, cm))
```

I just create my FlowableList and wrap it into a table. But actually the bulletType is `bulletType='1'` then I have my list with numbers. I tried to replaced this by `bulletType='-'` but this doesn't work.

Do you have an idea how can I replace all number by another symbol ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem. I found the [source code](https://bitbucket.org/rptlab/reportlab/src/1e4e0e4427ab10379bc0c75126ce60c8f8fe14f1/src/reportlab/platypus/flowables.py?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#flowables.py-43,1257,1893) on the reportlab's bitbucket.

Here is the list of the defaults shapes.

```
_bulletNames = dict(
                bulletchar=u'\u2022',  # usually a small circle
                circle=u'\u25cf',  # circle as high as the font
                square=u'\u25a0',
                disc=u'\u25cf',
                diamond=u'\u25c6',
                diamondwx=u'\u2756',
                rarrowhead=u'\u27a4',
                sparkle=u'\u2747',
                squarelrs=u'\u274f',
                blackstar=u'\u2605',
                )
```

I just have to add the start parameter and set what I want.

```
t = ListFlowable(
    [
        Paragraph("Item no.1", style),
        ListItem(Paragraph("Item no. 2", style), bulletColor="green", value=7),
        Paragraph("Item no.4", style),
    ],
    bulletType='1',
    start='-'  # You can use default shape or custom char like me here
)
```